# Can a US citizen vote in a US federal election if they don't live there?

Tags: voting

I am a dual citizen of Canada and the USA.  I have always lived in Canada, and I am interested in casting a vote for the next election in the United States.

**Is it possible for me to vote?** If not, why not? If it is, how can I do it?

Comment: Did either of your parents live in the US at any point in their lives? If so, what state? @user6726 Don't make assumptions like that. In 36 states you're wrong, and some US citizens who have never lived in the US may register to vote for at least federal office.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://www.fvap.gov/citizen-voter.

The rules vary slightly from state to state, but chances are good that you can vote in the state where your parents last lived in the US.

If you were born in the US, then it looks like you can vote in the state where you were born even if you didn't live there or even stay there for very long.

However, it's probably too late to vote in the 2016 presidential election because most if not all registration deadlines have passed, or will have passed by the time you mail in your registration form.